# How to explicitly call a namespace-qualified destructor?

Tags: c++, g++, standards, clang++

I am surprised that the following simple code won't compile (with gcc, version 4.8.1)

```
#include <string>
void test()
{
  std::string* p = new std::string("Destruct me");
  p->std::~string();
}
```

It says: error: scope ‘std’ before ‘~’ is not a class-name. Yet reading the standard, I would say the syntax says it should be "*postfix-expresssion* -> *pseudo-constructor-name*", where *pseudo-constructor-name* can be of the form "*nested-name-specifier* ~ *type-name*", and *nested-name-specifier* can be "*identifier*::".

Leaving out "std::" leads to the complaint that a class name was expected before the left paren, and putting it after the tilde to the complaint that a class name was expected before "::". After some trying I found that it will compile when written `p->std::string::~string();` (but not when one writes `p->std::string::~std::string();` instead). But qualifying the destructor with its own type name is not a neutral operation; I gather from the example in 12.4:13 of the standard (but curiously not from the normative text) that this forces the destructor of the exact static (base) class to be called, rather than as a virtual function that of (the most derived type of) the actual object pointed to. Here it makes no difference, but in similar cases it would; why would the syntax force exclusively using the static type?

However, with clang instead of gcc even the mentioned variant gives a syntax error. The error messages of clang are more amusing though, if you're in the mood for for this kind of humour when reading error messages: for `p->std::string::~string();` it gives "expected the class name after '~' to name a destructor" (and so it does; one wonders which kind of class names would not name a destructor if prefixed by a tilde), and for my initial trial `p->std::~string()` it retorts "qualified member access refers to a member in namespace 'std'" (again one wonders what is wrong with that; indeed the destructor to be called lives in the namespace 'std'). I've tried all 8 reasonable combinations (std:: and/or string:: before the tilde, and/or std:: after it) and none of them compile with clang.

I can make it compile, even with clang, using `using std::string;`. But what I find curious is that I can find no indication in the standard that such a declaration was intended to be necessary in such cases.In fact I can find nothing that addresses the issue of calling the destructor of a namespace-qualified class at all. Am I missing something obvious?

As a final note, I'd like to add that it strikes me as odd that one have to use a namespace qualification at all when calling a destructor. Since this is member access from a well specified object (here `*p`) shouldn't argument-dependent lookup make explicitly qualifying the namespace unnecessary?

Comment: I have to say that you are doing something terribly wrong, but the problem is interesting nonetheless.

Comment: For the record: `new T` does two things. It allocates raw memory and then initializes it via the constructor, whereas the `~T()` syntax only calls the destructor; the memory is still allocated.

Comment: This issue will never come up in practice. The pseudo-destructor calls are there mainly for templated code for cases such as `t.~T()` to allow generic code to be nicer for scalar types such as `int` because they don't have a destructor. Also note that this isn't exactly a pseudo-destructor call, rather it is an explicit destructor call and the way to call those is through `p->namespace::object~namespace::object()` as you've noticed. It's undefined behaviour for the destructor to be called twice though.

Comment: I'm calling bug on this. It's [also getting funny](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3cfc60d477795753).

Comment: By the way, the section in the standard that specifies this behaviour is §12.4/13.

Comment: Also, [here's Rapptz's version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bcf4fe8f49323d92)... not compiling.

Comment: @Rapptz: You are wrong that this never comes up in practice. I ran into this problem in practice, not quite as in the example of the question, but in cleaning up a variant of a `union`. The standard makes it clear (9.5:4) that explicitly destructing the old variant and placement-constructing the new variant is the proper way to change variants. And the destructor of a variant will **not** be called from the destructor of the union, which cannot know which variant is active. The explicit destructor call also occurs in the destructor of a containing class, which does know the active variant.

Comment: I don't suppose you tried `p->~basic_string();` ?

Comment: @WhozCraig The call should also work on `typedef`s and `using` aliases.

Comment: @Jefffrey I never said it shouldn't. I simply asked.

Comment: @WhozCraig `p->~basic_string()` does work.

Comment: @Rapptz I suspected as much.

Comment: @WhozCraig In regard to [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24593942/how-to-explicitly-call-a-namespace-qualified-destructor/24594393?noredirect=1#comment38104075_24594393), I'm saying it *should* because the standard explicitly shows an example in §12.4/13 in which `typedef` should work.

Comment: @Jefffrey I understand, but the posted examples in that part of the standard are *not* buried in a namespace (neither the classes nor the typedef alias). I can't say I know the standard well enough to discern whether the behavior (failure) through typedef is intended or it just coincidence *both* g++ and clang++ exhibit the same failure intentionally. And fwiw, a `using` alias exhibits the same fail (which I somewhat expected).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the standard, at:

> **§3.4.5/3**
>
> If the unqualified-id is ~type-name, the type-name is looked up in the context of the entire postfix-expression.

therefore it would seem that `~string` should be looked up in the context of the `std::` namespace.

In fact, considering that a corresponding home-made version works as follows on both GCC and Clang:

```
namespace STD {
class STRING {};
}

int main() {
    STD::STRING* a = new STD::STRING();
    a->~STRING();
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo with clang++</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3cfc60d477795753) [<kbd>Live demo with g++</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53863f1188888286)

I'll go ahead and say this is most likely a bug.

---

Apparently, given that `std::string` is really `std::basic_string<char>` if you call:

```
a->~basic_string();
```

[<kbd>Live demo with clang++</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/592087ecc3f4c0aa) [<kbd>Live demo with g++</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2cb7a19fb4098bf5)

then everything compiles fine.

I still remain of the idea that this a bug, considering that the following example (taken from the standard), shows that `typedef`s should also work:

```
struct B {
    virtual ~B() { }
};

struct D : B {
    ~D() { } 
};

D D_object;

typedef B B_alias;

B* B_ptr = &D_object;

void f() {
D_object.B::~B();
    B_ptr->~B();
    B_ptr->~B_alias();
    B_ptr->B_alias::~B();
    B_ptr->B_alias::~B_alias();
}
```

This notion, together with §3.4.5/3 should guarantee that:

```
p->~string();
```

should work.

Comment: Very curious. Are you suggesting this is something specific to the `std` namespace? Also note that your final example, which I mentioned in the question, does not compile if you replace g++ by clang++.

Comment: You may be surprised to alias that via typedef within the namespace. [Fails on g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7bf9455128423e16), and [Fails on clang++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f0c6120972461d9).

Comment: @Jefffrey yeah, its times like this I wish I spoke ADL like some of the folks on this board. I suspect its resolution is at the root of this (it usually is when pulling rabbits out of namespaces), but again, that I leave to denser gray matter.

Comment: Indeed the problem seems to be with the `typedef`. If in the first example you say, inside the `STD` namespace, `typedef STRING string;`, and then in the rest replace `STRING` by `string`, then it no longer compiles. I fail to see see why ADL should find a class name, but not find a typedef name defined _in the same namespace_.

Comment: Note that you can write `p->std::string::~string()`.

Answer (score 7):

**2019 update:** Starting from C++17, you can use [`std::destroy_at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/destroy_at) as follows:

```
std::destroy_at(p);
```

It's much simpler and follows the principle of not using "primitive constructs" (such as `new` / `delete` expressions) in modern C++.