# Why is there no built-in way to get a pointer from an std::optional?

Tags: c++, option-type, stdoptional

Things like the following happen all to often when using `std::optional`:

```
void bar(const Foo*);

void baz(const std::optional<Foo>& foo) {
    // This is clunky to do every time.
    bar(foo.has_value() ? &foo.value() : nullptr);
    
    // Why can't I do this instead?
    bar(foo.as_ptr());
}
```

This is the sort of thing that makes it annoying to adopt `std::optional`, because then it's extremely inconvenient to use it with existing code that expects pointers instead. So why isn't something like `.as_ptr()` provided with `std::optional`? It seems like a pretty obvious convenience function.

Comment: `&foo.value() ? foo.has_value() : nullptr` is not just "clunky" it is wrong. If `foo` does not contain a value then `value()` throws an exception.

Comment: did you perpahs swap `has_value` and `value` in the code?

Comment: You can still create a free function helper to do that... Resulting to `bar(as_ptr(foo));`.

Comment: Yes, whoops, my bad, been using too much Python lately lol. Will edit.

Comment: If you had that `as_ptr()`, you would need to check its result for `nullptr` at the place where this result was used. I don't see any benefit over checking whether an optional has some value.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from writing `T const* as_ptr(std::optional<T> const&)`.

Comment: @DanielLangr But `bar()` already does that. If I could re-write `bar()` and all other functions like it to use `std::optional` instead of a pointer, then I wouldn't need to do this.

Comment: what would annoy me much more is that `bar` takes its parameter by pointer. You can't blame `std::optional` for that :P

Comment: @DanielLangr: it is to inter-operate with "old" code (or C code, or ...) which uses (nullble) pointers.

Comment: @MSalters Nothing stopping me, but something so simple and frequent shouldn't require a roll-your-own helper function that I would then have to put in some util library and include it almost everywhere I use optionals.

Comment: It reminds my [question about missing `std::construct_at`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52966560/580083). A few years later, it got into the standard (not because of my question ;). But note that anyone can prepare a proposal for extending C++, including the addition of your desired function.

Comment: i suppose it has something to do with [`operator->`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator*) being undefined when the optional contains no value. If it could return a `nullptr` without incurring additional cost it would be the method you are looking for.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I don't think this explains anything. The -> operator has nothing to do with this. The as_ptr function that I would like to see would be an exact stand-in for the code I have above.

Comment: @Matt: "*something so simple and frequent*" Something that is "simple and frequent" for you may not be "simple and frequent" for other people.

Comment: "has nothing to do with this" ? Sorry I dont get that. It is the method that returns a pointer to the contained value. If it would return a `nullptr` in case there is no value, it would be a replacement for `foo.has_value() ? &foo.value() : nullptr`

Comment: @NicolBolas The simplicity is not relative. It is simple. It can be implemented as already shown above. Frequency is indeed relative, but I really do think that anyone who isn't writing new code from scratch but wants to adopt the std::optional paradigm would run into this situation.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number no it is not the "method that returns a pointer to the contained value". It is is the deference and call operator. You can't call a non-existent value anyway, that's why it has undefined semantics if there is no value. The way you get the pointer is as I have shown above. If you use the -> operator to get the pointer, then you are really doing something wrong.

Comment: @matt You can call `operator->` explicitly to get a pointer.  But, as 463 points out, the result is undefined if the `optional` doesn't contain a value, which is a bit of a shame.

Comment: @PaulSanders that's not what it's meant for. You can get a pointer as I have already demonstrated with `&foo.value()` or `&*foo`, but none of these options would safely return nullptr when the optional is empty.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To be pedantically correct, you need to use one of these instead:

```cpp
// `Foo` might have an overloaded `operator&`
foo.has_value() ? std::addressof(foo.value()) : nullptr
// You can shorten it to
foo ? std::addressof(*foo) : nullptr
// Or you can use `operator->()`
foo ? foo.operator->() : nullptr
// Which in C++20 can be accessed with a more readable utility function
foo ? std::to_address(foo) : nullptr
```

As for the "why", let's look at the proposal to add `std::optional` to the standard library, ["A proposal to add a utility class to represent optional objects (Revision 5)"](https://wg21.link/N3793).

It's based on [Boost.Optional](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html), which does provide `foo.get_ptr()` with the exact semantics that you want.

In fact, the [original proposal](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1878.htm) has `get_pointer(foo)`, but it was removed in the second revision. The change is described as "Removed duplicate interface for accessing the value stored by the optional.", as it was removed along with `std::get(std::optional<T>&)`.

You can simply use `boost::optional` instead, but it is not too hard to reimplement it yourself:

```cpp
// If you want it as a member
namespace my {

template<typename T>
struct optional : std::optional<T> {
    using std::optional<T>::optional;
    T* get_ptr() noexcept { return has_value() ? std::addressof(value()) : nullptr; }
    const T* get_ptr() const noexcept { return has_value() ? std::addressof(value()) : nullptr; }
};

}

// Or as a free function
template<typename T>
T* get_ptr(std::optional<T>& opt) noexcept {
    return opt.has_value() ? std::addressof(opt.value()) : nullptr;
}

template<typename T>
const T* get_ptr(const std::optional<T>& opt) noexcept {
    return opt.has_value() ? std::addressof(opt.value()) : nullptr;
}
```

---

Or using the C++23 [monadic operations on optionals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/and_then), this can be `foo.and_then([](auto& x) { return std::addressof(x); })`.

Comment: The pitfall of `std::addressof` usage give a point to provide it in std IMO :-)

Answer (score 3):

I don't have an official answer, but to me it's simply not *generic* enough to make sense in all cases.  `std::optional<std::shared_ptr<Foo>>` is perfectly *valid* (though we may question why someone takes this approach), as is `std::optional<Foo*>`.

So what would `as_ptr()` do in each of the above cases?  `std::shared_ptr<Foo>*`?  `Foo**`?  Those are the *correct* types per your request, but likely won't result in just drop in replacements in your code.

You could write a simple template for your use case if you like:

```
template <class T>
T* as_ptr(std::optional<T>& in)
{
    return in.has_value() ? &in.value() : nullptr;
}

// note C++20 allows this (more terse) signature
// auto* as_ptr(auto& in);

int main()
{
    std::optional<int> f;

    std::cout << as_ptr<int>(f);
}
```

Comment: I don't see any problem here. Yes, std::optional<Foo*>::as_ptr() would then return Foo**, which is exactly what older code would expect for an optional-pointer-to-Foo. I also believe that templated code is smart enough these days to disable a function in cases where it actually doesn't make sense. If it makes any difference, as_ptr can be named something more descriptive to make its semantics clearer in the general case.

Comment: why not just `as_ptr(f)`?

Comment: You don't need to specify the template argument when invoking `as_ptr`, since the argument `T` is deducable from the type of `optional` passed in: `std::cout << as_ptr(f);`

Comment: for C++20 I would preffer `auto* as_ptr(std::optional<auto>& in)` It's more explicit and restrictive.