# How to explicitly call the destructor on a templated item member

Tags: c++, generics, destructor

The following code (paste to godbolt if you like) compiles

```
struct array {
    ~array();
};

struct node {
    array children;
};

void foo(node* bar) {
    bar->children.~array();
}
```

But if i use a template the compiler gets a syntax error when i explicitly reference the template type. Why and is there a working solution?

```
 #include <vector>
 struct node {
     std::vector<node> children;
 };

 void foo(node* bar) {
     bar->children.~std::vector<node>();
 }
```

Comment: Why do you need to do that at all?

Comment: Okay, 42 seconds and i got a -1. 
I ask for C++ enlightment. Look at it as a puzzle. But there is a use case for it. I want to embedd a templated member variable into a Gtk/GObject structure which is preallocated by the constructor. So i have to invoke ctor and dtor explicitly.

Comment: Well, why would you call the destructor explicitly?

Comment: @Lothar So you have more or less a simple typo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd88157baf3c1bf8

Comment: @Lothar Also your question doesn't provide a [mcve], the exact error message is missing.

Comment: Possibly relevant question: [How to explicitly call a namespace-qualified destructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24593942/580083).

Comment: @Lothar what is the actual use case? Explicitly calling a destructor is only valid for something that has been allocated with `placement-new`. Are you allocating a raw memory block and calling `placement-new` for the `vector` constructor on that block? That does not make sense in the code provided.

Comment: Yes i use placement-new.  And as i said i use C++ objects with GObject objects (thats what Gtk uses).

Answer (score 4):

Clang is more helpful with the error message: `

```
 <source>:7:20: error: '~' in destructor name should be after nested name specifier
 bar->children.~std::vector<node>();`
```

So basically you'll need to rely on ADL (I'm no guru, so maybe it's the wrong name for the stuff you use to make it work :) ) here, and call: `bar->children.~vector<node>();`

Answer (score 3):

**Starting from C++17**, you can use [`std::destroy_at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/destroy_at):

```
std::destroy_at(&bar->children);
```

**Before C++17**, such a function can be easily implemented manually (outside of the `std` namespace, of course) as:

```
template<class T>
void destroy_at(T* p) { p->~T(); }
```

The usage is IMHO much nicer then invoking destructor explicitly, which brings problems with namespaces. See, e.g., [How to explicitly call a namespace-qualified destructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24593942/580083).

Answer (score 0):

As per [[class.dtor]/14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.dtor#14):

> In an explicit destructor call, the destructor is specified by a `~` followed by a *type-name* or *decltype-specifier* that denotes the destructor’s class type.

So remove the `std::` in the explicit call. 
However, explicit calling of a destructor is required only in certain cases such as using `placement new` to allocate memory. See this FAQ [answer](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#calling-member-dtors).